# using cache in IRewriteProvider class

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

How can I use cache from my web site, in my IRewriteProvider?

I know about using HttpRuntime.Cache["Key"] in a class library, but in this case with the provider, it seems that the cache is always null, even though it gets a value in the web site.

Any good ideas, as to how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to use ASP.NET caching? What about installing something like memcache/membase and using that?

Comment: It's because I have a website which handles all of the cached items (editing), and the class IRewriteProvider uses the cache.

I have no experience with memcache/membase.